# Reading LabVIEW TDMS files with R

Tags: r, labview

As part of a transition from MATLAB to R, I am trying to figure out how to read TDMS files created with National Instruments LabVIEW using R. TDMS is a fairly complex binary file format (http://www.ni.com/white-paper/5696/en/).

Add-ons exist for excel and open-office (http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3727/en/), and I could make something in LabVIEW to make the conversion, but **I am looking for a solution that would let me read the TDMS files directly into R**. This would allow us to test out the use of R for certain data processing requirements without changing what we do earlier in the data acquisition process. Having a simple process would also reduce the barriers to others trying out R for this purpose.

Does anyone have any experience with reading TDMS files directly into R, that they could share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is far from supporting all TDMS specifications but I started a port of a python npTDMS package into R here https://github.com/msuefishlab/tdmsreader and it has been tested out in the context of a shiny app [here](https://github.com/msuefishlab/tdmsviewer)

Comment: Accepting this as the current best answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say if you need to automate the reading of these files using R, or just convert the data manually. I'm assuming you or your colleagues don't have any access to LabVIEW yourselves otherwise you could just create a LabVIEW tool to do the conversion (and build it as a standalone application or DLL, if you have the professional development system or app builder - you could run the built app from your R code by [passing parameters on a command line](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/17C3AD70493CE0208625666A00763364)).

The document on [your first link](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3727/en/) refers to (a) add-ins for OpenOffice Calc and for Excel, which should work for a manual conversion and which you might be able to automate using those programs' respective macro languages, and (b) a C DLL for reading TDMS - would it be possible for you to use one of those?

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect these comments. I haven't figured  out how to make R use a C DLL: if you have any expertise in that area, I'd love to see some ideas.

Comment: None sorry, but see edited answer for link on how to pass parameters to LabVIEW built app via command line which you should be able to issue from R?

Comment: The 'Rcpp' package should help using the DLL. Once all the setup is complete, you can write C functions that will compile to R functions